# How to downgrade a Laravel 5.1 Project to 4.x?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, downgrade

How does one downgrade a Laravel 5 project to Laravel 4? If it's not that hard, it might work better for my team. Any changes in Eloquent, Controllers, views, and user logins would be the need-to-know. The primary reason we are looking to downgrade is host PHP support.  5.3/5.4 are what we'd need, so whichever version of 4 we use would need to go that far back - I guess I'm also looking for advice on which version of 4 would be good.

Comment: Will it work better for your team or your host? If you're considering downgrading just because of the host I'd rather suggest you change host... Anywho, I'd guess you could follow a [4 to 5 migration guide](https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0) - in reverse of course. Expect quite a bit of work though

Comment: It's more of a requirement to use the host that's an issue. @JimL.

Comment: L5 has change of directory and strcutue if you want to downgrade then you've to remove namespaces from model, controller, and move /resource/view to app/views controller to app/controller/ models to app/models